# Fetch id from Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to add a Modal to popup whenever i click a button to update the records i have stored in a database but i'm having trouble getting the id

```
    <?php

                                        //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
                                        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','pizzeria');

                                        //Output any connection error
                                        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                                        }
                                        //MySqli Select Query
                                        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, navn, indeholder, pris FROM pizza");
                                        print '<tr>';
                                        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            print '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
                                            print '<td>'.$row["navn"].'</td>';
                                            print '<td>'.$row["indeholder"].'</td>';
                                            print '<td>'.$row["pris"].'</td>';
                                            print '<td align="center"><button type="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Redigere</button></td>';
                                            print '</tr>';                                          
                                            }
                                        // Frees the memory associated with a result
                                        $results->free();

                                        // close connection 
                                        $mysqli->close();

                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Bekræft Venligst Sletning</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Er du sikker på at du vil slette <?php echo $rows['navn']; ?>?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
        <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Slet</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything i can do to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean you're unable to get  `$row["id"]`  ?

Comment: yes exactly! i get this error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\***\admin\pages\list.php on line 160

Comment: print '<td align="center"><button type="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$row['id'].'">Redigere</button></td>';

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the `$row` variable outside of the **while** loop that it's defined in.  You need to assign the array values from `$row` to new variables while you are in the loop.  Then, you'll be able to reference the values in the second half of the script.

```
$id_array = array();
$nav_array = array();
$indeholder_array = array();
$pris_array = array();

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    // Save the results to our globally scoped arrays
    array_push($id_array, $row["id"]);
    array_push($nav_array, $row["navn"]);
    array_push($indeholder_array, $row["indeholder"]);
    array_push($pris_array, $row["pris"]);

    echo '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["navn"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["indeholder"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["pris"].'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><button type="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Redigere</button></td>';
    echo '</tr>';                                          

}
```

In the above, I created four new arrays in the global scope to store each of the values returned from your SELECT query.

I also changed instances of `print` to `echo`.  You'll want to use `echo` in place of `print` when generating HTML mark-up.  `print` will evaluate the variables you pass into it and you might see wonky results if you use it to generate HTML.

Now when you want to grab these values in the second half of your script, you would use something like:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
      Er du sikker på at du vil slette <?php echo $nav_array[0]; ?>?
  </div>
```

Notice the `0` index key I am referencing when using the array.  Change this to match the value you want to get from the results.

Answer (score -1):

You're actually getting a PHP syntax error. On the 5th print inside the while loop:

```
print '<td align="center"><button type="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Redigere</button></td>';
```

Change it to

```
print '<td align="center"><button type="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$row['id'].'">Redigere</button></td>';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.